# How to map mydomain.com to a website created via google-apps where mydomain.com is not the primairy google apps domain

Tags: google-apps, google-sites

In other words, how can i map my-X-domainname.com to a website created with google-apps that is not the same domainname (i.e. my-Y-domainname.com)?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming my-Y-domainname.com is the primary Google Apps domain and you would like your Google Sites website to be reachable via my-X-domainname.com you will need to do the following:

1. Add my-X-domainname.com as a [secondary domain](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=53295) to your Google Apps domain.
2. Establish the mapping of www.my-X-domainname.com to the Google Sites site by following [these instructions](http://support.google.com/sites/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=99448).

Please note that you will not be able to map the naked domain my-X-domainname.com to the Sites page. Only subdomains of my-X-domainname.com (such as www.my-X-domainname.com) can be mapped.